# A question on Lagrange's Mean Value theorem.

Tags: calculus

Let $ f(x) = x^3+3x+2 $ and $ x=c $ be a point such that $(b-a)f'(c)$ is not equal to $f(b)-f(a)$ for ***any*** two values of $a,b\in \mathbf R$ then the number of such points are?

My answer:
I thought there will be no such points according to LMVT but the solution says that for such points $x=c , f''(c)=0$
And therefore there will be one such $c.$
But I don't get it.

Comment: It seems you're thinking about the mean value theorem backwards.  It says given $a,b$ you can find $c$, not given $c$ you can find $a,b$.  Am I missing something?

Comment: MVT guarantees that,

>for any interval $[a,b]$, we can pick $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$.

This is *different* from saying that,

>for any $c$, there exists a neighborhood $(a,b)$ containing $c$ such that $f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$.

The question of whether you can find $c$ such that, for *any* $(a,b)$ containing $c$, $f'(c)\neq\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ is yet another question.

Comment: @saulspatz They are asking about any a and b. Thus, what they are really asking is whether no such c exists for some a and b.

Comment: @AmitHegde I understand that.  I'm talking about the OP's statement that he thought the MVT implies it for all $c$.  I don't think this is a consequence of the MVT for any $c$.  I'm saying the same thing as Elliot G, though perhaps not as clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x%5E3%20%2B3*x%2B2&wal=header).  If you draw a tangent at the inflection point, it will lie below the graph on the right and above the graph on the left.  No line parallel to it intersects the graph twice.

I'm just reasoning from the picture.  I haven't proved it.  Why don't you try?

Comment: If we solve by this method inflection point is x=0 and slope is 3. Any line with slope 3, y=3x+k gives only one solution that is one point of intersection with f(x). Hence proved

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed $c$, consider the function

$$h_c(a,b):=f(b)-f(a)-(b-a)f'(c)=f(b)-f(a)-(b-a)(3c^2+3).$$

Notice that if you fix $a$, then $\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}h_c(a,b)=\infty$ and $\lim_{b\rightarrow-\infty}h_c(a,b)=-\infty$. Since $h$ is continuous in $b$, this means that by IVT there must be a point $b=b_c(a)$ such that $h_c(a,b_c)=0$. So there is no such $c$.